# Modify string, PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string, for example

```
20120201
```

I need to change it to

```
2012/02/01
```

obviously I need to add "/" after the 4th, 6th characters in the string.

Could someone help me do this in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try substring? Also you could try http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php if it is always date

Comment: I've been looking for a suitable method to do this and havn't found any (probably because of my lack of experience). I had a look at substring, I couldn't figure out how to use it with this specific example I need.

Comment: The direct answer to your question is the substr answers you've seen below, but if it is always a date you're talking about, the better answer is the strtotime function mentioned by others. It's more clear when you see your code later or someone else has to code behind you, what you were doing and why. (Trust me, 2 years from now, you'll be glad you did it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$final = substr($initial,0,4).'/'.substr($initial,4,2).'/'.substr($initial,6,2)
```

Use [substr](http://am.php.net/substr).

Comment: For info sake, the last `,2` is not required as substr will go to the end if the `length` isn't given

Comment: Thakns for info, didn't know.

Answer (score 3):

You could use substr, something like

```
$result = substr($str,0,4)."/".substr($str,4,2)."/".substr($str, 6)
```

edit: Messing between Java and Php for String concat :p

Comment: you mean "." instead of "+" .. this is PHP not java(script). FTFY.

Answer (score 1):

If you want inserting, you can use http://php.net/substr_replace

```
$string = "20120201";
$newString = substr_replace(substr_replace($string, "/", 6, 0), "/", 4, 0);
```

or concatenate substrings got by http://php.net/substr

```
$newString = substr($string, 0, 4) . "/" . substr($string, 4, 2) . "/" . substr($string, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [date_parse_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) to parse the date you have there into a PHP date object, then you could output it in any format you'd like.  A list of available date formats is located [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)